# Is it possible to use an Excel function to evaluate criteria using strings similar to how COUNTIFS() and SUMIFS() does?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

My issue is that I have a criteria written as a string in a cell, for example ">= 50" is in Cell A1. I am able to use this with SUMIFS and COUNTIFS easily since these functions take the boolean criteria as a string. So COUNTIFS(range, A1) would tell me how many items in the range are greater than or equal to 50.

I want to be able to do this with a function similar to IF (just something that evaluates a logical test) as well, but it seems like the only way to evaluate a boolean in the IF function is to use the actual boolean operations and not a string. So I want the equivalent of IF(range >= 50, 1, 0) when applied to an array (so the result should be a range of 1s and 0s depending on whether the condition is satisfied), but instead the syntax would be something like IF_new(range, ">= 50", 1, 0).

My final goal is to use the IF_new(...) style function inside a SUMPRODUCT() (like an indicator for which rows are to be included). So I am specifically looking for a way to do this using ">= 50" (so the boolean is contained inside a string and evaluated that way just like in COUNTIFS and SUMIFS) inside the function, rather than just >=50.

Is this possible without using VBA? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume *range* is a single cell. Why not just use COUNTIF? e.g. `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,  ">= 50"), 1, 0)` or `=COUNTIF(A1,  ">= 50")` if you just want a 1 or 0?

Comment: I want an array in the end. Let me edit the question so it is clearer

Comment: Plz [Edit] your post & share sample data along with the Criteria, help us to fix the issue.

Comment: The range is literally any range of numbers. Like a column of 1, 2, 3, 51 would suffice. And the criteria is ">= 50". I just want to know if it is possible to use the syntax of COUNTIFS and SUMIFS to evaluate booleans in an IF-style statement

Comment: First you need to deal with the fact that a standard IF doesn't take an array in the boolean argument. If you want an array formula IF, then what are you planning to do with the results?

Comment: An array style formula might be something like `=SUM(IF({1,2,3,51,52}>=50, 1, 0))` with CSE or `=SUM(IF(A1:A12>=50, 1, 0))` with CSE. The latter is the same as `=COUNTIF(A1:A12, ">=50")`.

Comment: @Slade,, Literally with `IF` what you are trying is not possible,, the `IF` never handle operators within quotes ,,, but Number as TEXT can be enclosed with quotes!!

Comment: I know it's not possible with IF. I'm asking if there's a similar function that can do this without using VBA

Comment: @Slade,, but this can be used `=IF(COUNTIF(I236:I246,">=1")=5,1,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard method to change `=">=50"` in a cell into a boolean IF statement. A reference to the cell containing `=">=50"` **can** be used in a COUNTIF or SUMIF but those don't typically work well in SUMPRODUCT formulas.

Use OFFSET to isolate each cell in a range as a singular *range* against the criteria as text in a COUNTIF to supply an On/Off in a SUMPRODUCT operation.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1, ROW(1:6), 0, 1, 1), A1), B2:B7, C2:C7)
```

[image]

You could probably accomplish this with EVALUATE and named ranges as well.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! It's a bit long and cumbersome but it does the job

Comment: @Slade,, the core issue was how to use `">=50"` with `IF` or `SUMPRODUCT` and the solution show above calculates `PRODUCT` to `SUM` based on criteria in `Column A` ,,, is totally different !!